# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataSet

Tags: c#, sql

I got this error after running the debbugger to see the error:

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataSet' to type
>   'NLHosp.DataSet"

"NLHosp" is the name of my database.

here is the code:

```
  private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string strUser;
        string strPass;
        string sMsg = "";

        strUser = txtUserID.Text ;
        strPass = txtPassword.Text ;

        DataSet o_Find = new DataSet ();
        Users oUsers = new Users();

        try
        {
            o_Find = (DataSet)oUsers.FindData(strUser,strPass);
            sMsg = "Welcome " + o_Find.Tables ["Login"].Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString ();

            switch (strUser)
            {
                case "Admissions":
                    frmAdmissions admitForm = new frmAdmissions ();
                    admitForm.Visible = true;
                    admitForm.Activate();
                    break;
                case "Admin":
                case "Nurse":
                case "Doctor":
                    frmMenu menuForm = new frmMenu ();
                    menuForm.oCurrent.UserName = strUser;
                    menuForm.Visible = true;
                    menuForm.Activate();
                    menuForm.SelectUser();
                    break;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've declared your own type called `DataSet` within the `NLHosp` namespace, and that's what you're trying to cast to - but the `FindData` is just returning a `System.Data.DataSet` object.

To start with, I'd *strongly* encourage you to rename `NLHosp.DataSet` so that it doesn't clash with existing system type names. Then you should consider what you *actually* wanted to cast it to. If you really meant to cast it to your custom type (and work), then you need to look at `FindData` and work out why it's only returning a `System.Data.DataSet`. It *looks* like you only need things from `System.Data.DataSet` though...

Comment: So What Do You Reecommend me to Do??kmatyaszek